# Please explain the cases in a given sentence

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative

I came across this sentence on a YouTube video:

> Lisa bringt morgen ihrem Vater das Geld.

It was mentioned that *ihrem Vater* takes Dativ and *das Geld* takes Accusative. I do not understand the cases of these objects. Can someone simplify/help me understand this?

There was no explanation of the cases in this video as the video was about another topic.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You correctly state the case of the two objects - yet you don't understand them? Please clarify what your question is about, what is not clear to you exactly.

Comment: If your question is about what is a dative case and what is an accusative case, I think this question is better suited on linguistics SE as it is not specific to German.

Comment: Similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/46026/1696). Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

The dative object tells who bears the result of the action. Often this is who receives the accusative object.

As the father receives the money, he is put as the dative object, and the money as the accusative object.

Answer (score 2):

Ihrem Vater is dative because she is bringing the item to him. Notice that the  word dative comes from the Latin "do, dare, dedi, datum" --meaning "give" in Latin. Generally, verbs that show giving, telling, or showing have an indirect object and a direct object. In this case, Vater is the indirect object because it indirectly receives the action Lisa performs. Lisa's action,"bringt", in turn, falls under the category of "giving."

Das Geld is the direct object. It receives the direct action of the verb. Direct objects go in the accusative.

Ask yourself:

1. Brings what? The answer is Geld. That indicates with 99% certainty it is the direct object and takes the accusative case.

Then ask yourself:

2. To whom/what, or for whom/what did she bring it? The answer is Vater, which indicates to a high probability that it is an indirect object and in the dative case. Sometimes this question will be answered by a prepositional phrase, which is why it's not 100% reliable, but if the noun or pronoun "stands alone" i.e. has no preposition, it is 99% sure to be the indirect object and therefore dative if it answers this question.

Comment: The concepts *direct* and *indirect object* do not exist in German and cannot be transferred one by one from English to dative and accusative in German and vice versa. Therefore, this answer is misleading more than it helps. (-1)

Comment: An English speaker was clearly the one asking this question, and it clarifies the issue very well in English. The objective case in English covers direct objects as well as objects of prepositions, for example, so to say that a direct object is in the accusative case does not rule out other uses of the accusative. To insist that every explanation correspond exactly to German in all ways would be to insist that they can be translated 1:1 word for word. Heuristics are important to understanding the language.

Comment: @sputnix while your argument in the comment has some merrit, your answer leads to believe these concepts exist in German - and not just a coarse guide which fails ever so often, and only may sometimes help when translating from English to German.

Comment: planetmaker, I must disagree. In no way does making a concept understandable to a foreign speaker stipulate that the terms used are used and must only be used the same way in German. I suppose you have a choice. Act as if you don't know what the person is talking about and give no answer, or try to help. I might also point out that the objective case in Engish is for both acc. and dative as well. So of course they don't correspond exactly.  If the person knew the fine points well enough to satisfy every possible objection to the question, then the person wouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: @sputnix Of course you can explain that *in this case* the accusative and dative objects in German correspond to direct and indirect objects in English, but I agree with the other comments that your wording is misleading.

Comment: Bodo, that is extremely pedantic in my opinion. Having taught grammar for 20 years +, you cannot explain everything every time just for the sake of completeness. The word A in the Oxford English Dictionary is hundreds of words long, for one example. There is already a lot in the explanation I gave. It's too often people say the question doesn't make sense and so forth. That's no help. But please let me know of how it's "misleading." I would be very interested to know. Maybe I can improve the explanation.